# I am getting "Unable to find the controller for path .... The route is wrongly configured." in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

My routing.yml file looks like this

```
video:
  path: /video/{utubeURL}
  defaults: {_contoller: SOMEHomeBundle:Home:video}
```

And in my HomeController the function the function look like this:

```
public function videoAction($utubeURL)
{
    $this->data['cssFiles'] = [*********];
    $this->data['utubeURL'] = $utubeURL;
    return $this->render('SOMEHomeBundle:Default:video.html.twig', $this->data);
}
```

But when I go to any link, I am getting the error "Unable to find the controller for path "/video/******". The route is wrongly configured."

I am searching Symfony 3 documentation and a search engine, but still no solution. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: When you run php bin/console debug:router, what do you get?

Comment: Each time you add a new route you have to clear the cache... Maybe You forgot to do it?

Comment: And make sure your HomeContoller has the correct namespace.

Comment: @MatkoĐipalo - this is what i get for video route "video                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /video/{utubeURL}"

Comment: @gp_sflover - i've cleared several times, still no help

Comment: @Cerad - this is the namespace for my controller "namespace SOME\HomeBundle\Controller;"

Comment: Can you find anything useful in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
  defaults: {_contoller: SOMEHomeBundle:Home:video}
```

Here should be _controller, not _contoller :)

---

HttpKernel:

```
// Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php

// load controller
if (false === $controller = $this->resolver->getController($request)) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Unable to find the controller for path "%s". The route is wrongly configured.', $request->getPathInfo()));
}
```

ControllerResolver:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * This method looks for a '_controller' request attribute that represents
 * the controller name (a string like ClassName::MethodName).
 */
public function getController(Request $request)
{
    if (!$controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller')) {
        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            $this->logger->warning('Unable to look for the controller as the "_controller" parameter is missing.');
        }

        return false;
    }
...
```

In the controller resolver, if the attribute '_controller' does not exist, false is returned. That triggers exception in the Http Kernel.